# how to map java boolean type to postgresql Char(1) in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I cannot use yes_no type in hbm file . Is there a way in which i can create a custom dialect such that it maps boolean to char(1) ?

Comment: Why don't you use a real `boolean` in the database?

Comment: Actually we used char(1) for old database which is in mysql. We recreated all the tables in postgresql. Now changing the type would consume a lot of time in checking and debugging the code. The databases are huge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can map the column like this

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType")
@Column(name = "IsValid", columnDefinition = "CHAR(1)", length = 1)
private Boolean valid;
```